# Combine two datetime variables into one

Tags: c#

I have two `datetime` variables and I want to combine them together.

This is the code that I have so far:

```cs
Int32 addDay = Convert.ToInt32((ucWait.model.SelectMCCodeAskOutObj as SelectMCCodeAsk_OUT).PRIORITY);
this.dp_RST.SelectedDate = CommonServiceAgent.SelectSysDate().AddDays(addDay);
```

It is reading from sysdate; I'm trying to change it to read from another variable. This is my attempt of doing so:

```cs
Int32 addDay = Convert.ToInt32((mcnon.model.SelectMCCodeAskOutObj as SelectMCCodeAsk_OUT).PRIORITY);
this.dp_RST.SelectedDate = (dgFUList.SelectedItem as SelOutOrderInfo_OUT).NEXT_DAY.AddDays(addDay);
```

I get an error that `AddDays` is not defined

> (System.Nullable<System.datetime> dose not contain a definition for 'AddDays' and no extension method 'AddDays' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.datetime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )   )

Comment: What's the type of `SelOutOrderInfo_OUT.NEXT_DAY`?

Comment: Could you add the exact error message to the question?

Comment: its not a function

Comment: @phuzi i add the error msg

Comment: Was that error copied and pasted? There are spelling errors

Comment: no i did write it myself .... ops @phuzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly states that it's coming on this line.

```
this.dp_RST.SelectedDate = (dgFUList.SelectedItem as SelOutOrderInfo_OUT).NEXT_DAY.AddDays(addDay);
```

This is because `NEXT_DAY` Property in `SelOutOrderInfo_OUT` Type is `Nullable<DateTime>`.

You can do

```
this.dp_RST.SelectedDate = (dgFUList.SelectedItem as SelOutOrderInfo_OUT).NEXT_DAY.Value.AddDays(addDay);
```

However, you can check if the value is not blank otherwise you can run into issues.

**Better Solution**

```
var dt = (dgFUList.SelectedItem as SelOutOrderInfo_OUT).NEXT_DAY;

if (dt.HasValue)
    this.dp_RST.SelectedDate = dt.Value.AddDays(addDay);
```

Comment: @matt Accepted without upvoting the answer. Ouch! ;)

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." give me the source code of satckoverflow lemme change this condition lol ..

Comment: @matt - lol. While we are at it, can you give admin rights to my account? ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `SelOutOrderInfo_OUT.NEXT_DAY` is of type `Nullable<DateTime>` (DateTieme? is syntactic sugar for the same) and `Nullable<DateTime>` doesn't contain a method `AddDays()`

You should first verify that `.NEXT_DAY` doesn't return a null value and then call `AddDays()` on the underlying value.

Depending on the version of C# you are using you should be able to do

```
this.dp_RST.SelectedDate = (dgFUList.SelectedItem as SelOutOrderInfo_OUT).NEXT_DAY
    .Value? // Check for null before attempting to add days.
    .AddDays(addDay);
```

Comment: it worked bur without the ? with the value ... thanks a lot for your efforts and support